# Class variable pointing to a method behaves different

Tags: python

Class variables do not behave like regular variables. When calling a class variable as a method, it's not being called as if it was just a regular variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def func():
    print 'func called'

class MyClass(object):
    FUNC = func

    def call_func(self):
        MyClass.FUNC()

instance = MyClass()
instance.call_func()
```

Produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    instance.call_func()
  File "main.py", line 9, in call_func
    MyClass.FUNC()
TypeError: unbound method func() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: You should probably specify what you expect instead of just saying "does not behave as I expect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this to work as expected, you must decorate `FUNC` with `staticmethod()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def func():
    print 'func called'

class MyClass(object):
    FUNC = staticmethod(func)

    def call_func(self):
        MyClass.FUNC()

instance = MyClass()
instance.call_func()
```

Comment: Note that this is [not required in Python 3](http://python-history.blogspot.in/2009/02/first-class-everything.html) anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a very straightforward solution:

```
def func():
    print 'func called'

class MyClass(object):
    def FUNC(self):
        return func()

    def call_func(self):
        MyClass.FUNC(self)

instance = MyClass()
instance.call_func()
```

The difference is that when you call `MyClass.FUNC()`, you should pass the instance.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this in first place is I'm pointing to a function inside the `os` module, monkey patching it when running tests. The reason I can't monkey patch the `os` function directly is it still needs to work as usual in other parts of the code.